# Gradient calculation not disabled in no_grad() PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Why is the gradient calculation of `y` not disabled in the following piece of code?

```
x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
print(x.requires_grad)
print((x ** 2).requires_grad)
y = x**2
print(y.requires_grad)
with torch.no_grad():
    print((x ** 2).requires_grad)
    print(y.requires_grad)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
True
True
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the official documentation says that the results would have `require_grad=False` even though the inputs have `required_grad=True`

> Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, when you are sure
>       that you will not call :meth:`Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory
>       consumption for computations that would otherwise have `requires_grad=True`.
>       In this mode, the result of every computation will have
>       `requires_grad=False`, even when the inputs have `requires_grad=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific implementation of `torch.no_grad()`， but the doc contains the sentence ***the result of every computation*** which means it only works for the result but not origin variable.
run code below:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    print(x.grad)
```

which will give output:

```
True
```

So as `y` which is not the `result` arising within `torch.no_grad()` context.